# POST correctly sent but $_POST and $_FILES arrays are empty

Tags: php, http, post

I'm trying to send a picture from an IP security camera to my Web server via an HTTP POST message. Although the file transfer seems to be done correctly, the global $_FILES and $_POST arrays remain empty.

**Server**: XAMPP for OS X 5.6.39, Apache 2.4.37
**Client**: MOBOTIX IP cam (Linux based with modified packages)

Please note that I don't have control on the client-side code because we are talking about an embedded system which gets locked down by the manufacturer and, most importantly, it's very likely that the binary used to send the request is not standard at all (source code modified and re-compiled for the host system).

To troubleshoot the issue I replaced the IP camera with a more standard tool like cURL and with that everything works as expected.

```
$ curl -v "http://localhost/test/test.php" -F "file=@pic.jpg"
```

And here is the expected result:

```
<pre>
POST dump:
array(0) {
}
FILES dump:
array(1) {
  ["file"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "pic.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(45) "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpz8TOrR"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(11706)
  }
}
</pre>
```

Hence I would assume that there is nothing wrong with my page or with my Web server but I would like to figure out what is preventing the $_FILES array from being populated.

Here is the code of my PHP page:

```
<?php

sleep(2);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if (!empty($_POST) || !empty($_FILES)) {

        echo "<pre>\nPOST dump:\n";
        var_dump($_POST);
        echo "FILES dump:\n";
        var_dump($_FILES);
        //print_r($_FILES);
        echo "</pre>\n";
        exit();

    } else {

        echo "Empty POST\n";
        exit();

    }

} else {

    echo "Only POST requests allowed\n";
    exit();

}   

?>
```

Below the result of a Wireshark trace performed on the IP camera:

```
POST /test/test.php HTTP/1.0
Host: 192.168.1.100:80
User-Agent: mxmsg/2.2 (mx10-9-151-2; 10.9.151.2; MX-V4.4.1.55)
Accept: */ *
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="mxmsg_qswteervteuliaodpj9a7b5i3_20050405"

--mxmsg_qswteervteuliaodpj9a7b5i3_20050405
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="/tmp2/clipdir21301/E00000.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 9256

<IMAGE DATA, less than 10 KB>

--mxmsg_qswteervteuliaodpj9a7b5i3_20050405--

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 17 May 2019 12:27:12 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.37 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2q PHP/5.6.39 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.39
Content-Length: 11
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Empty POST
```

Additional info received via the camera logs:

```
INF: loading notify profile...
INF: set profile address "192.168.1.100:80"
INF: set profile http version: "HTTP/1.0"
INF: set profile http cgi path: "/test/test.php"
INF: set profile http authorize: ""
INF: using 'now' for base time
INF: add file '/tmp2/clipdir21301/E00000.jpg' to list
INF: [hdl#1] connection established (ip=192.168.1.100, port=80, fd=2) ...
INF: reached data limit of 512 bytes ... (stop reading)
INF: [hdl#1] HTTP-Headers: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
INF: [hdl#1] HTTP-Headers: Date: Fri, 17 May 2019 07:28:20 GMT
INF: [hdl#1] HTTP-Headers: Server: Apache/2.4.37 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2q PHP/5.6.39 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
INF: [hdl#1] HTTP-Headers: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.39
INF: [hdl#1] HTTP-Headers: Content-Length: 53
INF: [hdl#1] HTTP-Headers: Connection: close
INF: [hdl#1] HTTP-Headers: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
INF: notification to 192.168.1.100:80 has been sent [msg okay=1].
INF: Server 192.168.1.100:80 response HTTP code 200.
Result:
INF: sending message succeed. 1x9256 bytes in 2.877s.
```

Result of a Wireshark trace performed on a cURL request:

```
POST /test/test.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.100
User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
Accept: */ *
Content-Length: 9486
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------7aa5e6b4427813b7
Expect: 100-continue

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

--------------------------7aa5e6b4427813b7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="pic.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<IMAGE DATA, less than 10KB>

--------------------------7aa5e6b4427813b7--

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 17 May 2019 12:32:03 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.37 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2q PHP/5.6.39 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.39
Content-Length: 323
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<pre>
POST dump:
array(0) {
}
<pre>
FILES dump:
array(1) {
  ["file"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "pic.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(45) "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phptisqiC"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(9297)
  }
}
</pre>
```

Any hint would be greatly appreciated!

[Edit]

I ran another test on a different server (IIS 10 with PHP 5.3); I used the very same PHP code but in this case the server returns a 411 Length Required error message which, I believe, has something to do with the way the camera declares the content length.

```
POST /test/test.php HTTP/1.0
Host: 192.168.1.100:80
User-Agent: mxmsg/2.2 (mx10-9-151-2; 10.9.151.2; MX-V4.4.1.55)
Accept: */ *
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="mxmsg_qswteervteuliaodpj9a7b5i3_20050405"

--mxmsg_qswteervteuliaodpj9a7b5i3_20050405
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="/tmp2/clipdir21301/E00000.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 9256

<IMAGE DATA, less than 10 KB>

--mxmsg_qswteervteuliaodpj9a7b5i3_20050405--

HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Thu, 23 May 2019 09:22:32 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 344

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Length Required</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Length Required</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

According to [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html), chapter 4.4 Message Length...

> If a request contains a message-body and a Content-Length is not
>   given, the server SHOULD respond with 400 (bad request) if it cannot
>   determine the length of the message, or with 411 (length required) if
>   it wishes to insist on receiving a valid Content-Length.

... and the debug information reported above clearly shows that the camera includes the length of the attached image BUT NOT the one of the whole request. Now the question is: why does XAMPP (Apache) return a 200 OK whereas ISS returns 411 Length Required?

Comment: In the camera log, could this be a problem: INF: reached data limit of 512 bytes ... (stop reading)

Comment: What about sending small image? ~1kb size or so

Comment: I might be wrong but I believe that “stop reading” does not refer to the camera’s internal buffer for the queue rather to the data (response) that is coming back from the server. Moreover, I wouldn’t know how to generate an image <1KB with the camera because the minimum resolution in 160x120 px and even if I use a solid color, say black, that would be at least a few KB.

Comment: To me it’s like that the server starts responding even before the client completes the file transfer.